# How can I publish records that I am getting through a Meteor.method() call

Tags: meteor

I am getting a set of documents from a call to a function in Meteor.methods(). Now I want to publish these documents in a local collection which should be client only. How can I do this?

```
Meteor.methods({
    fillCollection: function (userId) {
        var record = Meteor.call('checkedOutRecordIds', userId);
        var results = Meteor.call('getCheckedOutDocuments', userId, record);
        // I want to store these results in a local collection.
        // I have tried it, but it doesn't let me.
        results.forEach(function (doc) {
            localCollection.insert(doc);
        });
    }});
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the method have side effects other than returning documents?

Comment: No, the method doesn't have any side effects. It just queries the different collections and returns a set of documents.

Comment: I don't think you can use Meteor.call inside a method